# Need Help in Writting Matlab Code for Sum of Independent Random Variables

Tags: matlab, parameters, numerical-integration

I want to write a MATLAB code for the [convolution of density functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Sums_of_independent_random_variables) .

For random variables X (with PDF f_x)and Y(with PDF f_y), the PDF of their summation, X+Y, can be obtained by the following MATLAB code:

```
function p=sumX_Y(z,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2)
G = @(y)f_x(mean1,sigma1,z-y).*f_y(mean2,sigma2,y);p= integral(G,-Inf,Inf);
```

Now for summation of three random variable X+Y+Z it should be

```
function p=sumX_Y_Z(z,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2,mean3,sigma3)
    G = @(y)sumX_Y(z-y,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2).*f_z(mean3,sigma3,y);p= integral(G,-Inf,Inf);
```

But it will not work since the first input of the function sumX_Y is not of type double. I would appreciate if you could help me to fix this problem.

I also want to find the PDF for sum of more than 3 random variable and I do not know how to write the algorithm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

One way to perform the convolution is as follows:

First define `sumX_Y`

```
function p=sumX_Y(z,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2)

f_x = @(x) normpdf(x,mean1,sigma1);
f_y = @(x) normpdf(x,mean2,sigma2);


for ii=1:length(z)

    G = @(y)f_x(z(ii)-y).*f_y(y);
    p(ii)= quad8(G, ...
                 min([mean1,mean2])-3*max([sigma1,sigma2])  ,...
                 max([mean1,mean2])+3*max([sigma1,sigma2])    );
end
```

The loop in the function above can be vectorized using the `bsxfun` notation btw.

Then define `sumX_Y_Z` as follows:

```
function p=sumX_Y_Z(z,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2,mean3,sigma3)

f_z = @(x) normpdf(x,mean3,sigma3);
G = @(y)sumX_Y(z-y,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2).*f_z(y);

p= quad8(G,min([mean1,mean2,mean3])-3*max([sigma1,sigma2,sigma3]),...
           max([mean1,mean2,mean3])+3*max([sigma1,sigma2,sigma3]));
```

The whole thing can be called as follows:

```
mean1=1;
sigma1=0.3;
mean2=2;
sigma2=1;
mean3=0;
sigma3=1;

X = 1.4; % <-- value at which to evaluate p

p=sumX_Y(X,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2)
p=sumX_Y_Z(X,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2,mean3,sigma3)
```

with output:

```
p =

    0.1181


p =

    0.1494
```

You can modify the functions to use `integral` instead of 'quad8', and substitute your definition of `f_z` etc of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a number to a double like this:

```
numberAsDouble = double(number);
```

So either convert the number before calling `sumX_Y`, or force it to be converted in the function itself:

```
function p=sumX_Y(z,mean1,sigma1,mean2,sigma2)
  G = @(y)f_x(mean1,sigma1,double(z)-y).*f_y(mean2,sigma2,y);p= integral(G,-Inf,Inf);
```

You could do this for all the inputs if you like.

Comment: the problem is z actually